# loop adding component in reactjs

Tags: reactjs

How to add component card in loop?
How to do it in right way?
All snipet here https://jsfiddle.net/oL1gawfo/

```
    ...
        for(let i=1;i<5,i++){
          var colorhex="#FFA"+i+"56";
          ReactDOM.render(
            <div>
              <Card color=colorhex/>
            </div>,
            document.querySelector("#c"+i)
          );
        }
  ...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i just found another way.

```
var colors = ["#393E41", "#E94F37", "#1C89BF", "#A1D363",
              "#85FFC7", "#297373", "#FF8552", "#A40E4C"];

var renderData = [];

for (var i = 0; i < colors.length; i++) {
  renderData.push(<Circle bgColor={colors[i]}/>);
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <div>
    {renderData}
  </div>,
  destination
);
```

Answer (score 1):

The syntax of your for loop is incorrect. You need `;` to separate your for loop expressions and not a `comma`

```
for(let i=1;i<5;i++){

      var colorhex="#FFA"+i+"56";
      console.log(colorhex);
      ReactDOM.render(
        <div>
          <Card color={colorhex}/>
        </div>,
        document.querySelector("#c"+i)
      );
    }
```

**[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/oL1gawfo/1/)**